# Expect script is running only one command and displays an error

Tags: unix, expect

**SCRIPT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username "sv111111"
set password "Sandy789"
set f [open "servers.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
foreach host $hosts {
#spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hosts
spawn ssh $username@$host
expect "$username@$host's password:"
send -- "$password\n"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo -u sandy /opt/sandy/ship/common/tools/arpq.sh\n"
expect "$username@$host's password:"
send -- "$password\n"
expect "$"
send -- "sudo -u sandy /opt/sandy/ship/common/tools/showps2.pl\n"

expect "$"
send -- "exit\n"
expect eof
close
}
```

in the above script it perfectly runs the first sudo command for all the servers mentioned in the servers.txt file . second sudo command is not executing and its showing the below error.

```
spawn ssh sv111111@
ssh: : Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp10 not open
    while executing
"send -- "$password\n""
    ("foreach" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
#spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hosts
spawn ssh $username@$host
expect "$username@$host's password:"
send -- ..."
    (file "./sandy_try.sh" line 8)
```

please help

Comment: Hi @Glenn jackman: I Need to send the log files of the server using mail to two users. can you please help ?

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: I am unable to ask glenn. I am no more able to ask the new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` command grabs the file contents *with a trailing newline*. Then, when you split on newlines, the list has a trailing element that is an empty string. Use one of these:

```tcl
set f [open "servers.txt"]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
# .....................^^^^^^^^^^
close $f
foreach host $hosts { ...
```

or

```tcl
set f [open "servers.txt"]
while {[gets $f host] != -1} {
    spawn ssh ...
}
close $f
```